# How can i print particular documents with particular printers in different times

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, printing, web-application

I have a print button in a web application, which on click will generate and print two receipts(Receipt A & Receipt B) at a time. Right now the print is coming to a single printer(Printer X). I want the Receipt A to be print in Printer X & Receipt B to be print in Printer Y without selecting the printer every time.
Is there any way to crack this issue

Comment: Are you the app developer?

Comment: Yes, i am an odoo ERP developer. I want this feature to be implemented in Odoo

Comment: While the browser may not have this permission, the server definitely does. So long as the printers are accessible from the application server, you should be able to generate whichever print jobs to whatever printer you want. However, if the printer is not accessible to the server, then harrymc is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - the browser will not allow it as a security feature,
to avoid unwanted prints to vulnerable printers.

The browser leaves the choice of the printer entirely to the operating system
and what it allows to the user.
The Web developer may customize the content to be printed, depending on which
button is clicked, but choosing the printer is only done by the user.

The only way to do that is by developing an extension to the browser that
will initiate the print to a specific printer.

Comment: Even chrome extension there is restrictions. Printer control is restricted

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using a commercial solution like [Ricoh Print&Share](https://www.printandshare.info). You just always print to Print&Share and let it do the routing and selection of the printer(s).
Depending on the needs this may be configured in different ways, e.g. two profiles using profile recognition. a single profile splitting the input job with two print channels and using page definitions.

Comment: jufo thanks for your reply, i have used a similar solution qz.io